# for loop inside for loop error

Tags: android, for-loop

In Android app I want to assign different tags for first and second buttons (after you press any of those). My code is bellow. LogCat shows me that it executes inner for loop once and then turns off VM and also gives message ***"threadid=1: thread existing with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)"***. Thank You for help.

```
int marked = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int a = i + 1;

    for ( i = 0; i < priorities.size(); i++ ) 
    {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting button one tag: " + i );
            Log.d(TAG, "blablabla rank2 " + priorities.get(i).rank);
            button_one.setTag(i);
            button_one.setText(priorities.get(i).name);

            for (a = i + 1; a <= priorities.size(); a++)
            {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting whilee: " + i );
            Log.d(TAG, "blablabla while " + priorities.get(i).rank);
            button_two.setTag(a);
            button_two.setText(priorities.get(a).name);

            }       
    }
```

Comment: Post your detailed logcat message please.

Comment: the `<=` in the `a` loop is going to fail when you try `priorities.get(a)`, because in it's final iteration, a will be the size of priorities, which is zero indexed (I'd assume)

Comment: It's possible for "a" to be a larger index than priorities can be, for one.

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: the whole thing is like this:
I add the strings (eg. 1 2 3) in different text fields. then I want to compaire those in pairs(1 with 2, 1 with 3, 2 with 3). the first string element is written on the first button, second on the second and after i press any of those buttons, the tags on the buttons has to change (if there was 1 and 2 so it should change to 1 and 3 or 2 and 3 etc). Maybe You know the better way how to do that... I had not alot of experience with Android...

yes, it is indexed zero.
MrZander, how to do that?
Thank You

Comment: don't catch exceptions that can be fixed like in your case (change the `<=` to `<`)

Comment: Thank You all, Your advices helped! I changed <= to < now it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure but I don't think you really want to use a nested for loop in this situation.  Chances are you want this instead:

```
int marked = 0;
int i = 0;
int a = i + 1;

for ( i = 0; i < priorities.size(); i++ ) 
{
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting button one tag: " + i );
        Log.d(TAG, "blablabla rank2 " + priorities.get(i).rank);
        button_one.setTag(i);
        button_one.setText(priorities.get(i).name);

        Log.d(TAG, "Setting whilee: " + i );
        Log.d(TAG, "blablabla while " + priorities.get(i).rank);
        button_two.setTag(i);
        button_two.setText(priorities.get(i).name);
}
```

If you really do want the nested loop, You're not being consistent with your loop counter (the outer loop is zero indexed, but the inner loop is one indexed, and you're operating on the same types of object.  In that case you'd want this:

```
int marked = 0;
int i = 0;
int a = i + 1;

for ( i = 0; i < priorities.size(); i++ ) 
{
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting button one tag: " + i );
        Log.d(TAG, "blablabla rank2 " + priorities.get(i).rank);
        button_one.setTag(i);
        button_one.setText(priorities.get(i).name);

        for (a = i; a < priorities.size(); a++)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting whilee: " + i );
            Log.d(TAG, "blablabla while " + priorities.get(i).rank);
            button_two.setTag(a);
            button_two.setText(priorities.get(a).name);
        }       
}
```

Though I'm not 100% sure.  It's difficult to tell without definitions for all of your variables (what are button_one and button_two? what is priorities?)

Comment: priorities is that number of string elements